# How to force a child Card to the next line using Wrap widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have this container with 6 child Cards with Text inside. How do I force the 5th item to wrap to the next line so that I have 4 items in the top row and 2 in the bottom?
And also how do I prevent different screen resolutions from affecting my layout?

Here's what I have so far...

```
Flexible(
  child: Container(
    height: 220,
    child: Wrap(
      runAlignment: WrapAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          child: Card(child: Text("this is my ")),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: Card(child: Text("this is my ")),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: Card(child: Text("this is my")),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: Card(child: Text("this is my ")),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: Card(child: Text("this is my ")),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: Card(child: Text("this is my ")),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: use two row inside column, 4 item in first row, 2 item in second row

Comment: Create two Columns() inside the container's children. Use a Row() inside first column and put first 4 Flexible in that Row().Put remaining 2 Flexible into second column.

Comment: you can try with increasing the width of specific item